# How do I use xpath to find child and display the parent's information

Tags: xml, xpath, pattern-matching

At the moment, I have pretty much able to pull the child of the xml file.  But I want to be able to also "search" the parent info by matching the child.  So example is:

```
<parent>
......
     <child id=20>
     </child>
</parent>

<parent>
..
    <child id=30>
    </child>
</parent>
```

I want to display everything within that parent of child id=30

so far I got /parent/child[@id=30] , it only displays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the child attribute value this way:

```
/parent[child[@id="30"]]
```

Or, just FYI, you can also find child first, then get one level up:

```
/parent/child[@id="30"]/..
```